# Exchange ListBox items between two separate projects

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Lets say we have a project in C# that add's with the help of a button text from a textbox to a listbox.[image: Project 1]

And now lets say we have a second project **where we don't have the source code** and we would want to send the items from our listbox to each independent textbox in project number 2[image: Project 2]

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Comment: May I ask for a guidance on about how is this possible?

Comment: Well Joey, you got me curious.

Comment: I agree with @joey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are ways. From the error-prone but easy-to-write injecting keystrokes into the other application's input queue ([SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx), combined with giving the other application the keyboard focus first) to the more refined ways of [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx) and directly fiddling with the Windows API to change the text boxes' contents by sending [WM_SETTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644(v=vs.85).aspx). This varies depending on what the other application is written with (e.g. custom UI frameworks often don't use native Windows controls, nor support accessibility).

The SendKeys approach can be made much more robust by using the clipboard, especially regarding characters that may not exist on the keyboard. For a one-off task I'd probably do that. I have done something similar once to migrate my RSS feeds from one application to another by scripting this in PowerShell. If you seek robustness you should look into the other options. UI Automation can be cumbersome to work with, but at least offers APIs to deal with this directly (although you'd have to pick up a bunch of concepts to understand how to use it). The Windows API route would require you to understand fairly well how Windows works underneath the .NET framework.

Comment: Using [WM_COPYDATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) could also be possible, but you need to have access to the others application source code and implement it, if you cant have that UIAutomation is the way to go

Comment: @prizm1: I think you could also simulate a drag & drop operation into those text boxes. You'd probably still need the Windows API or UI Automation to figure out where they are, though. IMEs or something like Windows' Math Input Panel probably work similarly to send input to arbitrary applications.

Comment: Yep, it all involves programming ;)

Comment: May I just ask on how can you give the other application the keyboard focus,and thank you for the answer it was very educating. :)

Comment: @John: [SetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx), for example. Yet, it requires Windows API again. You could also ask the user to do so and have a little timer before sending keystrokes. Or ask the user and check the current foreground window yourself, not starting until the correct one is focused, etc.